# Strange glitching when using keyframes/ noise to move the camera

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

https://youtu.be/mTBQbwhs60Y-video of glitching
the camera and the car are both on follow path constraints, the camera has noise modifiers on it to add some rotation to the camera to give some camera shake this all works fine however when I try to add some forwards and backwards motion to move the camera closer and further from the car either via keyframes or a noise modifier it makes the car glitch out (as seen in the video) it happens even if the backwards and forwards motion is applied to the camera, not the car but it also glitches the same if I apply it to the car, if anyone has any ideas on how I could work around this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion. Please place an image in your question. The image can be independent of the link.

Comment: maybe increase the resolution of the curve?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger i didn't include an image since I'm not sure how that would help as the glitching can only be seen when played as a video hence why I linked the video in the comment

Comment: @moonboots thanks for the response, the curve resolution for the video was set at 256 but just upped it to the max and it's still happening, unfortunately, thanks for the idea though!

Comment: You can show the graph of the noise and place the cursor at the point which you call a [glitch].  You can write .... I see [glitch] at frame NNN. Any graph can contain data which can be interpreted by  [you] as a visual glitch.  Please show graph of noise and your curve modifiers for inspection.  Keyframes with a large difference between starting key and ending key with a cycles modifier can certainly produce discontinuity. Regarding your lack of image so far in the question ... it might do you some good to get different viewpoints from different data.

Comment: maybe share your file (remove the setup and replace the car by a simple cube): https://blend-exchange.com/